# Solving an equation with Sympy symbols

Tags: python, solver, sympy

Is the following code not solvable by Sympy? I've executed this code a couple of minutes ago, but it printed `n = 5` on the screen and it stuck.

```
import sympy

Wmin = 31
m = 8

p = sympy.symbols('p')

for n in range(5, 10):
    print 'n = %3d' % n

    denominator = (1 + Wmin + p * Wmin * ((1 - (2 * p) ** m) / (1 - 2 * p)))
    right = 1 - (1 - 2 / denominator) ** (n - 1)

    p_solve = sympy.solve(sympy.Eq(p, right))

    print p_solve
```

Actually, I've solved the equation with bisection method in MATLAB and I'm currently modifying without bisection method and porting in Python.

Comment: just to let you know... doing `sympy.solve(right, p)` it returns a `[]`...

Comment: I also tried `sympy.roots(sympy.Poly(right))` and it says: `multivariate polynomials are not supported`

Comment: It would probably help if you specify in `solve` or `roots` with respect to what argument you want the equation solved. And be aware that `roots` is only for polynomials which your equation is not. And if it raises "NotImplementedError: explanation" it means what it says: it is not implemented yet.

Comment: Well, I've re-expressed sum of Geometric sequence `Sum (2p)^k` during the modifying and porting. It might cause some problems which is represented as `((1 - (2 * p) ** m) / (1 - 2 * p)))`. It cannot solvable if `solve` approaches to p = 1/2. (Actually, I don't know how `solve` solves problem. just if.) So I replaced that expression with `sum([(2 * p) ** k for k in range(0, m )])`. But... it still doesn't work. So I currently gave up `solve` and use bisection method. :(

Comment: Do you expect the solution to have a closed-form algebraic representation? If you only care about numerical solutions, then `sympy.solve` is the wrong tool for you.

Comment: no. I expect a numerical soltion. The part of formula in the text and another in the comment is equivalent except p = 1/2

Answer (score 1):

You could use nsolve to solve a problem like this -- but you need a guess as to where the solution(s) might be:

```
>>> for n in range(5, 10):
...     print 'n = %3d' % n
...     denominator = (1 + Wmin + p * Wmin * ((1 - (2 * p) ** m) / (1 - 2 * p)))

...     right = 1 - (1 - 2 / denominator) ** (n - 1)
...     p_solve = nsolve(sympy.Eq(p, right),p,0)
...     print p_solve
...
n =   5
0.181881594898608
n =   6
0.210681675044646
n =   7
0.235278433487669
n =   8
0.256480923202426
n =   9
0.27492972759045
```